# How can I remove entirely Qt from Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I am trying to install Qt on Ubuntu 22.04.
Although I used MaintenanceTool to uninstall, I have difficulties.
The installation process seemingly is smooth, but when I attempt to compile using my CMakeLists.txt, I receive error message

```
Multiple versions of Qt found please set DESIRED_QT_VERSION
```

If I use DESIRED_QT_VERSION as advised, the error message is

```
CMake was unable to find desired Qt version: 6. Set advanced values QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE and QT6_QGLOBAL_H_FILE.
```

How can I imitate a clean installation; i.e. remove any tracks from Qt5 and Qt6?

My screen shows [image]

I just want to make a default installation, without any trick, which works. Is it possible to reset Qt, and hoping that next time the online install will work?

Comment: I have 3 versions of Qt in my ubuntu system and I never have had this problem, you should create a Kit and define your Qt version there.

Comment: You know, I need only one kit, and I wanted to know how can I get rid of the unwanted one. Or, to use one of the available ones.

Comment: I think qt doc write about this, https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html

Comment: You should see settings of that kit and decide which one you want or you could create one manually

Answer (score 0):

Please Look at the image below, I have 3 different versions of Qt:

[image]

but each version has one kit that I can select

[image]

you can also create a kit and choose one version from that combo box.

It doesn't matter if you are using Cmake or Qmake you need **the correct Kit**